# Java SimpleJPA for AWS SimpleDB Select Query

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm having trouble getting objects back out of SimpleDB using the simpleJPA persistance API. I have successfully installed all the jars and can persist objects no problem. However I cannot seem to retrieve objects using select queries - but weirdly I can get results using count queries. There are no errors or exceptions, the queries simply don't return any results. When I debug I can view the actual AWS Query that is being generated in the background by simpleJPA, and when I run this query against a domain it returns the expected results no problem.

I've included my Java code below, it should return me a list of all the users in my database.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u");
List<User> results = (List<User>)query.getResultList();
```

As I said I can persist objects and count them, so there isn't anything wrong with my entity manager or factory, its just returning empty lists. If you need any more information just ask,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got to the bottom of this problem. In the end I started a new AWS project in Eclipse and re-added the JAR files, solving the issue.